# Spring MessageSource Interface Implementation

Tags: java, spring

I am using the `getMessage`method from the `MessageSource` interface on a `AbstractApplicationContext` object (that implements the `MessageSource` interface) in the code below:

```
AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
System.out.println(context.getMessage("greeting", null, "Default Message", null));
context.registerShutdownHook();
Shape t = (Shape) context.getBean("circle");
t.draw();
```

And below is my property file (`mymessages.properties`):

```
greeting=Hello!
```

For some reason when I run the code above it keeps printing out `Default Message` instead of taking the value of the key `greeting` in my property file and logging that to the screen (which is `Hello!`).

But when I include this in my `spring.xml` it somehow works:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>mymessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I am confused on why I have to add a bean for the class `ResourceBundleMessageSource` when the `AbstractApplicationContext` object already implements the `MessageSource` interface which has the implementation of the `getMessage` method.

How does adding the `ResourceBundleMessageSource` bean make this work?

Comment: `AbstractApplicationContext` _delegates_ to the appropriate configured `MessageSource`. Realistically though, unless you're just playing around, there should be no reason to use the `ApplicationContext` directly, and calling `getBean` is Code Smell TM.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Can you elaborate on that please? When you say delegate do you mean that the `AbstractApplicationContext` doesn't actually implement the `getMessage` method but when an object of `AbstractApplicationContext` calls that method it will go up all the classes that it inherited from and whichever class implemented that method fully the `getMessage` method will be called from there? So would that mean the `AbstractApplicationContext` extends the `ResourceBundleMessageSource` since that is where the `getMessage` method would be defined?

Comment: What you're speaking of is [inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html), not [delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern). Essentially* `AbstractApplicationContext` implements the `getMessage` method by calling `getBean("messageSource").getMessage`. *not actually how it works, but for illustration purposes it will do. Note also, that Spring is [open source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.java).

Comment: Ohh ok that makes more sense. This might be a stupid question but since the `AbstractApplicationContext` delegates the call to the `getMessage` method to the `MessageSource` interface how does the correct implementation of the `getMessage` method from the `MessageSource` interface get called? Since I saw on the docs that there are many classes which implement the `getMessage` interface. Or it just selects the class to call the `getMessage` based on whichever class you load in memory from the spring.xml like the `ResourceBundleMessageSource`.

Comment: As I pointed out, Spring is open source - it would be a useful educational experience for you to work this out on your own. Lines 708-736 and 1270-1276 would be a good place to start.

Comment: Ok thank you for all the help. Will definitely look it through it more thoroughly.